# How can i make multiple text so that it can show 3 data in a block in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show three data block of column, that is include date, title, and content. How can i do it? I only show 1 data that's title [main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTBwS.png)

Here's my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(child: ListTile(title: Text('One-line ListTile'))),
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(listBlog[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(listBlog[index].content),
                trailing: Text(listBlog[index].date),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )

        // ListView.separated(
        //     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        //       return ListTile(
        //         title: Text(listBlog[index].title),
        //         trailing: Text(listBlog[index].date),
        //         subtitle: Text(listBlog[index].date),
        //       );
        //     },
        //     separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        //       return Divider();
        //     },
        //     itemCount: listBlog.length),
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget. Three `Text` will be the child of the `Column`.

```
Column(
   children: const <Widget>[
    Text(...),
    Text(...),
    Text(...)                            
   ])
```

Code looked like this:

```
ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
            Divider(height: 1, color: Colors.grey),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: listBlog.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                 listBlog[index].title,
                ), Text(
                 listBlog[index].content,
                ), Text(
                 listBlog[index].date,
                )
              ]);
        });
```

Comment: How can i pass my API in this field? I.e `Text(listBlog[index].title)`

Comment: it same like how you did for the title. `Text(listBlog[index].data)`,`Text(listBlog[index].content)`.

Comment: I cant do it.. I show some errors even

Comment: What is inside `listBlog[index]`?

Comment: It refer to my API, that is

`List<Blog> listBlog = [];
  Repository repository = Repository();
  getData() async {
    listBlog = await repository.getData();
  }`

Comment: What is inside `Blog` ?

Comment: This one
```class Blog {
  final int id;
  final String date;
  final String title;
  final String content;

  const Blog({
    required this.id,
    required this.date,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
  });

  factory Blog.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Blog(
      id: json['id'],
      date: json['date'].toString(),
      title: json['title']['rendered'].toString(),
      content: json['content']['rendered'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this should work `Text(listBlog[index].date),Text(listBlog[index].content)`

Comment: No, it doesnt. The error says 'Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.',  'Invalid constant value.', etc

Comment: Remove the ·`const` keyword. If the error still persists, please update your post by pasting latest code.

Comment: Okay, just a sec please.. i'll update it

Comment: Okay, i've updated it.. but i use card

Comment: the error shows in which line?

Comment: Line 59 with msg 'Undefined name 'index'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.'

Comment: use `ListView.builder` or `ListView.seperated` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: I did it, but it didnt work though. But it is 

Thank you so much mate ✨

Comment: paste your latest code.

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(listBlog[index].title),
                trailing: Text(listBlog[index].date),
                subtitle: Text(listBlog[index].link),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider();
            },
            itemCount: listBlog.length),
        );
  }

Comment: What error you get??

Comment: No, i meant. It works, without any error 

Comment: Yeah, but can you edit it using ListView.seperated?

Comment: no problem, done.